# Retrieving selected option angularJS with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-select

I'm traying to retrieve the selected option from the HTML view with AngularJS, but I do not find the way since all the solutions I have seen take into account the parameter "value", but I do not have it here because I do not know the content of the option list beforehand.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<h5>Satellite selection</h5>
<div>
<select  id="selectedSatellite">

    <option ng-repeat="sat in passes">
        {{sat.SAT_NAME}}
    </option>

</select>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use following code. `ng-options` directive automatically creates `option` elements according to the provided array. `ng-model` retrieves the selected value

```
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="sat.SAT_NAME for sat in passes">
</select>
```

Also see following example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
    $scope.selectedName = "";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<h3>Selected Value : {{selectedName}}</h3>
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names">
</select>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ng-model` directive to get the selected value in the controller.

```
<div>
<select ng-model="selected"  id="selectedSatellite">

    <option ng-repeat="sat in passes">
        {{sat.SAT_NAME}}
    </option>

</select>
</div>
```